How to perform parallel data migration using Python
I want to perform data migration between tables in parallel. For example, I have data for cities A, B, and C. Let's say the data migration takes about 30 minutes. Migration of cities A and B is done at 1 am. Then city C at 1.10 am.
In the code that I wrote, migration cannot run in parallel. Migration of city C will be done after cities A and B are finished.
How can I do that? The following is the generated data that I created:
import pandas as pd import random

# Defining column names
columns = ['ID', 'Name', 'City', 'City_ID', 'Revenue']

# List of cities and corresponding city IDs
cities = {
    'New York': 1,
    'Los Angeles': 2,
    'Chicago': 3,
    'Houston': 4,
    'Phoenix': 5 }

# Generating 1000000 rows of dummy data
data = {
    'ID': range(1, 1000001),
    'Name': [f"Customer_{i}" for i in range(1, 1000001)],
    'City': [random.choice(list(cities.keys())) for _ in range(1000000)],
    'Revenue': [round(random.uniform(20.0, 500.0), 2) for _ in range(1000000)] }

# Creating City_ID based on the City column
data['City_ID'] = [cities[city] for city in data['City']]

# Creating DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Displaying the first few rows of the DataFrame
print(df.head())

# Optionally, you can save the data to a CSV file
df.to_csv('D:/INSAN/Document Project/dummy_data.csv', index=False)

city_flagging table



1
New York
0
0
0




2
Los Angeles
0
0
0


4
Houston
0
0
0


5
Phoenix
0
0
0


3
Chicago
1
0
0



Here is the code for data migration:
import pyodbc
import datetime
import time
import concurrent.futures

# Save migrated cities
migrated_city_ids = set()

# Function to get is_available = 1 status from database
def check_flagging_status():
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={PostgreSQL ODBC Driver(UNICODE)};server=localhost;port=5433;database=postgres;uid=postgres;pwd=postgres')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    query = "SELECT * FROM city_flagging WHERE is_available = 1 AND is_running = 0"
    cursor.execute(query)

    available_cabangs = cursor.fetchall()

    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

    return available_cabangs

# Function to update is_running and is_success status in city_flagging table
def update_flagging_status(city_id, is_running=None, is_success=None):
    conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={PostgreSQL ODBC Driver(UNICODE)};server=localhost;port=5433;database=postgres;uid=postgres;pwd=postgres')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    try:
        if is_running is not None:
            query = "UPDATE city_flagging SET is_running = ? WHERE city_id = ?"
            cursor.execute(query, (is_running, city_id))
        
        if is_success is not None:
            query = "UPDATE city_flagging SET is_success = ? WHERE city_id = ?"
            cursor.execute(query, (is_success, city_id))
        
        conn.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error while updating flagging status for city {city_id}: {e}")
    finally:
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

# Single city data migration function
def migrate_data(city_id, city_name):
    if city_id in migrated_city_ids:
        print(f"City {city_id} already migrated before, skip migration.")
        return

    # Update is_running to 1 (migration process is running)
    update_flagging_status(city_id, is_running=1)

    date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
    start_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()

    conn_old = pyodbc.connect('Driver={PostgreSQL ODBC Driver(UNICODE)};server=localhost;port=5433;database=postgres;uid=postgres;pwd=postgres')
    cursor_old = conn_old.cursor()

    conn_new = pyodbc.connect('Driver={PostgreSQL ODBC Driver(UNICODE)};server=localhost;port=5433;database=postgres;uid=postgres;pwd=postgres')
    cursor_new = conn_new.cursor()

    try:
        query = f"SELECT * FROM dummy_data WHERE city_id = '{city_id}'"
        cursor_old.execute(query)
        transaksi_data = cursor_old.fetchall()

        print(f"Data migration for city {city_id} is in progress.")
        insert_query = "INSERT INTO dummy_data_1 (id, name, city, revenue, city_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
        cursor_new.executemany(insert_query, transaksi_data)

        conn_new.commit()

        end_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()

        log_query = """
        INSERT INTO migration_log (date, city_id, city_name, start_datetime, end_datetime) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        """
        cursor_new.execute(log_query, (date, city_id, city_name, start_datetime, end_datetime))
        conn_new.commit()

        # Update is_success menjadi 1 (migrasi berhasil)
        update_flagging_status(city_id, is_success=1)

        migrated_city_ids.add(city_id)
        print(f"Data migration for city {city_id} is complete.")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error while migrating data for city {city_id}: {e}")
    
    finally:
        cursor_old.close()
        conn_old.close()
        cursor_new.close()
        conn_new.close()

# Function to start migration
def start_migration():
    city_list = check_flagging_status()

    if not city_list:
        print("There are no cities available for migration.")
        return False  # Tidak ada city yang tersedia

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        for city in city_list:
            city_id = city[0]
            city_name = city[1]
            executor.submit(migrate_data, city_id, city_name)

    return True  # There is a migration underway

# Function for periodic checks
def continuous_check(interval_seconds=2, max_no_migration_attempts=3):
    no_migration_attempts = 0

    while no_migration_attempts < max_no_migration_attempts:
        print("Checking flagging city status...")
        migration_started = start_migration()  # Check and migrate if there is a new city available

        if migration_started:
            no_migration_attempts = 0  # Reset trial if there is a migration running
        else:
            no_migration_attempts += 1  # TAdd trial if no city available

        if no_migration_attempts >= max_no_migration_attempts:
            print("No cities available for migration in multiple attempts. Stopping the process.")
            break

        time.sleep(interval_seconds)  # Wait for the specified interval

# Run periodic checks in parallel
continuous_check(1, 3)


Are you sure that the database allows more than 2 (or even 4, since you use 2 per city) connections in parallel?

Yes of course. Because when I migrate data for city A and B they can run in parallel.

That's what I meant, does the database allow 6 connections so that you can run 3 migrations in parallel?

What should happen when one of your queries fails halfway or a database connection is interrupted?
